# razor validation in partialview and ajax form not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have the following PartialView

```
@model Token.Creator.Site.Models.Customer
@{
    var cusModel = new Token.Creator.Site.Models.CustomerModel();
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
    HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
}
<div class="modal fade" id="customereditmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditCustomer", "Customer", new AjaxOptions(), new {
        @class = "modal-dialog form-horizontal",
        id = "upload_s0pin"
    })) { 
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Companyname)) { 
                    <h4 class="modal-title">@Model.Gender.Type @Model.Title @Model.Firstname @Model.Lastname</h4>
                } else {
                    <h4 class="modal-title">@Model.Companyname</h4>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Companyname, "Firmenname", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Companyname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Companyname);
                </div>
                <h4>Ansprechpartner</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Gender, "Anrede*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(cus => cus.Gender, new SelectList(cusModel.Gender.ToList(), cusModel.Gender), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Title, "Titel", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Title);
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Firstname, "Vorname*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Firstname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Firstname);
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Lastname, "Nachname*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Lastname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Lastname);
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Emailaddress, "Emailadresse*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Emailaddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Emailaddress);
                </div>
                <h4>Adresse</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Street, "Straße und Hausnummer*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Street, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Street);
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.ZIPCode, "Postleitzahl*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.ZIPCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.ZIPCode);
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Town, "Stadt*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Town, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Town);
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(cus => cus.Country, "Land*", new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(cus => cus.Country, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cus => cus.Country);
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Speichern" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The modelclass is autogenerated by EF. And I extend it to apply validation attributes.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetadata))]
public partial class Customer {
    private class CustomerMetadata {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie einen Vornamen ein")]
        public object Firstname;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie einen Nachnamen ein")]
        public object Lastname;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie eine Straße ein")]
        public object Street;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie eine Postleitzahl ein")]
        public object ZIPCode;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie eine Stadt ein")]
        public object Town;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie ein Land ein")]
        public object Country;
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Emailadresse ein")]
        public object Emailaddress;
    }
}
```

But the validation doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: **The partial view is loaded by AJAX**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I just needed to add the following script in the partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#customereditmodal > form");
    });
</script>
```

Where `customereditmodal` is the id of the div.

Here is the link to the solution http://forums.asp.net/post/4299121.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want just validation, ensure that your `EditCustomer` action method has this structure:

```
    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // It's ok! do what you need
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form            
        return View(model);
    }
```

If you want unobtrusive validation - if something is wrong, form won't be posted - you need to enable it in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Install `Jquery Validation` and `Microsoft JQuery Unobtrusive Validation` nuget packages.

And finally, add the following scripts to your main layout (or register them by bundles):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")></script>
```

Please note that the order of including above scripts are important and if add in the different order, unobtrusive validation doesn't work...

Comment: Ok, I have all the stuff for unobstrusive validation, but it doesn't work, what am I missing?